# what is the accurate command_line for deleting a folder in /usr/local?

Tags: command-line, rm

i was unsuccessful for installing jdk8 and i want to delete the java folder in my usr/local.

```
cd /usr/local
rm java
error :rm: cannot remove ‘java’: Is a directory
rmdir java
error :rmdir: failed to remove ‘java’: Permission denied
```

what is the accurate cmd line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo rm -r /usr/local/java` will suffice. `sudo` gives you the appropriate permissions to delete the directory and the `-r` ("r" stands for recursive) option is needed to delete the contents of the directory recursively.

Please make sure you intend to delete the `/usr/local/java` directory before running the command above.